# Sync Folders with Powershell - New and edited Files

Tags: powershell

I am trying to Sync 2 Folders with Powershell.
Comparing and copying any new Files works just fine. But I want to additionally copy all files that got modified in the reference Foler.

The following Code works and copys all new Files which got created in the reference Folder.

```
$folderReference = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TestA'
$folderToSync = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TestB'

$referenceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $folderReference 
$FolderSyncFiles = Get-ChildItem -recurse -Path $folderToSync

$fileDiffs = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $referenceFiles -DifferenceObject $FolderSyncFiles 

foreach ($File in $fileDiffs){
    try {
            if ($File.SideIndicator -eq "<="){

                $FullSourceObject = $File.InputObject.Fullname
                $FullTargetObject = $File.InputObject.Fullname.Replace($folderreference, $folderToSync)

                Write-Host "copy File: " $FullSourceObject
                copy-Item -Path $FullSourceObject -Destination $FullTargetObject
            }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error -Message "Something went wrong!" -ErrorAction Stop
    }
}
```

Now I also want to copy the modified Files.
I tried `-property LastWriteTime` after the `Compare-Object`but I get a WriteErrorException when running the code.

Do you guys have some tips on how to get this Code to run properly?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd just use robocopy, it's built specifically for this type of task

Comment: +1 for robocopy. can you share the error message you get? maybe put `throw $_` in your catch to see what the error is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just use robocopy, it's built specifically for this type of task and included in most modern versions of windows by default:

```
robocopy C:\Source C:\Destination /Z /XA:H /W:5
```

- `/Z` - resumes copy if interrupted
- `/XA:H` - ignores hidden files
- `/W:5` - shortens wait for failures to 5 sec (default 30)

Worth taking a look through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) as there's many different options for practically every situation you can think of...

For example, add `/MIR` and it will remove any files from the destination when they are deleted from source.

Comment: But this would just copy everything from Source to Destination.
My goal is to copy only files which are new or modified in the Source Foler.
Would that also be possible?

Comment: No it won't, Robocopy doesn't copy files if they are identical in source/destination.

Comment: Thank you. I got it working way easier than I thought!